# Nuget Error "Unable to find a version of 'Unity' that is compatible with 'NakedObjects.Core 7.1.3 constraint: Unity (>= 3.5.1404 && < 4.0.0)'."

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package-restore

I get

> Unable to find a version of 'Unity' that is compatible with
>   'NakedObjects.Core 7.1.3 constraint: Unity (>= 3.5.1404 && < 4.0.0)'.

When I try and update any package in VS 2017. I have the latest version of nuget. And the current version that is install in my project is indeed Unity 3.5.1404.